# Matrix Elements Sum C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on a problem (for fun) that is honestly making me confuse myself.

If I have a matrix like so:

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2], 
          [0, 5, 0, 0],
          [2, 0, 3, 3]]
```

I want to find the **sum** of all numbers that are **not** `0` and where a `0` is not above it.  Here is the same matrix broken down into the numbers that I want to add up:

```
matrix = [[x, 1, 1, 2], 
          [x, 5, x, x],
          [x, x, x, x]]

matrixSum = 9  // (1 + 1 + 2 + 5)
```

I am traversing the array based on column first then retrieving the value I am looking for, but I don't know how to ignore the values where a `0` lies above it.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] list1 = new int[4] { 0, 1, 1, 2};
        int[] list2 = new int[4] { 0, 5, 0, 0};
        int[] list3 = new int[4] { 2, 0, 3, 3 };
        int[][] lists = new int[][]{list1, list2, list3};

        var result = TestMethod(lists);
    }

    public static int TestMethod(int[][] matrix)
    {
        var lstOfIntsToAdd = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                Console.Write("matrix[[{1}][{0}]] = {2} /", j, i, matrix[j][i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        return return lstOfIntsToAdd.Sum();

    }
}
```

Here is the [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ta8bU0).

Any help is appreciated.

Picture from codefights:

[image]

This problem can be found on [CodeFights](https://codefights.com/arcade/intro/level-2/xskq4ZxLyqQMCLshr)

Comment: This is not a matrix, it's a jagged array. And when dealing with jagged arrays you have no guarantee that all the inner arrays have the same length. In fact, that's why it's called a jagged array in the first place... A matrix is a two dimentional array - `[,]`.

Comment: Could you please explaing what you mean by saying _and where a 0 is not above it._? Thanks

Comment: @ZoharPeled this problem is on CodeFights, and I thought to myself too that this was a 2 dimensional array but was thrown off because the method that they started for me and expect me to write the solution in is expecting a parameter of an array of arrays

Comment: @ZoharPeled see my picture

Comment: I don't know what CodeFights is, but they obviously got it wrong :-)... It's more than nitpicking, I'm afraid, you have to take this into consideration when writing your code.

Comment: @Christos any number (other than 0), that has a `0` above it I don't want the sum of.  In my 2nd code snippet I show the values that I **don't** want by replacing them with `x`

Comment: It would be more helpful if you added a link to the problem on [codefights](https://codefights.com/)

Comment: @Igor see my update.  I don't know if everyone can access it though because these challenges have to be unlocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check the row above if it exists:

```
public static int TestMethod(int[][] matrix)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            if (row == 0 || matrix[row - 1][column] != 0 )
                sum += matrix[row][column];
    return sum;         
}
```

Because C# uses [short-circuit evaulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of logical expressions, we can check if we are on the first row first and if we are, the body of the `if` statement will be evaulated without trying to access the non-existent `-1`st row of the matrix.

### Update

If the you should discard all values above which there is any zero, you can go through each column and add numbers as long as you don't encounter a zero.

```
public static int TestMethod(int[][] matrix)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        {
            if (matrix[row][column] != 0)
                sum += matrix[row][column];   
            else
                break;
        }
    return sum;             
}
```

Comment: as I understand, the author meant that all elements under 0 should be discarded

Comment: What do you mean by schwartz :-D ?

Comment: @Devstr I have updated the answer with the other alternative as well

Comment: With an array of arrays, how do you dynamically get the column and width size other than just statically entering `4` and `3` for the iterations?

Comment: [Space balls](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=i+see+your+schwartz+is+as+big+as+mine&rlz=1C1LENP_iwIL718IL718&oq=I+see+your+s&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.15120j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you look to young to know what I'm talking about :-)

Comment: The outer list is the number of rows (meaning `matrix.Length == 3`) and the inner list is the number of columns (meaning `matrix.First().Length == 4`). Of course, this has the prerequisite that the matrix is actually rectangular.

Comment: Happy coding :-) !

Comment: @MartinZikmund sorry to keep bothering you, but I think I'm confusing myself more and more lol `matrix[[0],[0]] = 0`, `matrix[[1],[0]] = 1`, and so on  and so on.. can you explain how to find the value of `matrix[[1],[0]]`.. I thought it was 1st row and the first element in the row.. which is in `list2`, `0`.

Comment: Nvmd, confusing myself.. it's column and then first element in the column.

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, lists.First().Length)
    .Sum(column =>  Enumerable.Range(0, lists.Length)
        .Select(row => lists[row][column])
        .TakeWhile(value => value != 0)
        .Sum())
```

---

Here is some explanation for the uninitiated:

== First layer ==

1. `Enumerable.Range(0, lists.First().Length)`: enumerate all the column indexes
2. `.Sum(column => ...`: Aggregate the results of inner(second) layer through summation

> Essentially, we take the column index, project the index into the desired value, and sum them up.

== Second layer ==

> While we are in the inner layer, throw away the notion of outer layer for now. As we will be focusing on each individual column.

3. `Enumerable.Range(0, lists.Length)`: same as step#1, but with row indexes
4. `.Select(row => lists[row][column])`: project the row indexes into values on the respective indexes.
5. `.TakeWhile(value => value != 0)`: allow us to skip `0` itself and every number after(below) it
6. `.Sum()`: add up everything

Comment: How does that deal with the "row above"? It is kinda late here but from what I understand this only sums values that are different than 0....

Comment: `TakeWhile` is the key here.

Comment: Maybe it's the time (past 23:00 here), but I tested it and still don't understand how that works exactly... and I have been working with linq for a while.... Some textual explanations would make this answer better.

Comment: It is a very cool solution. First it creates a Enumerable of 4 items (size of the first list) - 0,1,2,3. Then for each of these `columns` it creates a range 0,1,2 (rows), and selects from the `matrix`'s column items until a zero is encountered and sums those. Finally it sums the sums from of each of the columns.

Comment: @MartinZikmund Thanks, I don't know how I've missed that.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I've included some explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:
For the first row, you sum all values.
For any other row, you check if the array in the row before is too short (meaning there can't be a 0 above current number) or if the current index on the row before does not contain 0.
Please note that the order of the conditions is critical - if you change it you will cause an IndexOutOfRange exception.

You could add a check if the current value is different than zero, but adding zero to the sum is a no-op anyway so why bother?

```
public static int TestMethod(int[][] Jagged)
{
    var sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Jagged.Length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Jagged[i].Length; j++){
            if(i == 0 || Jagged[i-1].Length > j || Jagged[i-1][j] != 0) 
            {
                // you could add if Jagged[i][j] != 0 but it's a sum so who cares? 
                sum += Jagged[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

(in pseudo-code)

- set `sum` to 0
- make an array `mask` of length equal to matrix width (number of columns), fill it with 1
- for each row `i`

  - for every column `j` in the row `i`

    - if `matrix[i,j]` is zero, set `mask[j]` to 0.
    - `sum += matrix[i,j]*mask[j]`
- return `sum`

Here's the code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] list1 = new int[4] { 0, 1, 1, 2};
        int[] list2 = new int[4] { 0, 5, 0, 0};
        int[] list3 = new int[4] { 2, 0, 3, 3 };
        int[][] lists = new int[][]{list1, list2, list3};

        var result = TestMethod(lists);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static int TestMethod(int[][] matrix)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        // fill the mask with ones
        int[] mask = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 4).ToArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                    mask[j] = 0;
                }
                sum += matrix[i][j] * mask[j];
            }
        }
        return sum;

    }
}
```

Output:

> 9

You probably want to make number of columns and rows configurable.

Comment: Disregard my comments (now deleted), I missed how the value of `mask` is maintained between iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a 2D array instead of jagged arrays to avoid uncertainties about indexing higher dimensions:

```
int[,] matrix = new int[,]
{
    { 0, 1, 1, 2 }, 
    { 0, 5, 0, 0 },
    { 2, 0, 3, 3 },
};

Int32 sum = 0;

// Using row-major-order, so the indexer is [y,x] instead of the traditional [x,y]
for( int y = 0; y <= matrix.GetUpperBound(0); y++ )
for( int x = 0; x <= matrix.GetUpperBound(1); x++ )
{
    int cell = matrix[y,x];
    bool hasZeroAboveCurrentCell = y > 0 && matrix[y-1,x] != 0;

    if( cell != 0 && !hasZeroAboveCurrentCell )
    {
        sum += cell;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine( "Total: {0}", sum );
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you with your fiddle(add these after    `Console.Write("matrix[[{1}][{0}]] = {2} /", j, i, matrix[j][i]);)`:

```
int ttl =0;                 
if (j == 0)
    ttl += matrix[j][i];
if (j > 0)
    if (matrix[j-1][i] != 0)
        ttl += matrix[j][i];
```